# Azure DevOps Server: Migrating Test Cases - Expecting end of string error

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I am attempting my first migration between two different collections on Azure DevOps Server 2019.

The new collection has a custom inheritance process model.

I am trying to migrate test cases only for now. I would like to migrate test cases, test suites, and test plans.

I have added the configuration as per my understanding, but the migration keeps on failing.

Error message:

```
migration.exe Warning: 0 : [EXCEPTION] Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException: Expecting end of string. The error is caused by «BY».
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Query.Initialize(WorkItemStore store, String wiql, IDictionary context, Int32[] ids, Int32[] revs, Boolean dayPrecision)
```

Redacted Processor from the config file below.

Thanks!

```
  "Processors": [
    {
      "ObjectType": "VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.Configuration.Processing.NodeStructuresMigrationConfig",
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "Enabled": false,
      "BasePaths": [
        "****\\Market Regulation\\Market Surveillance - Bonds",
        "****\\Trading Value Stream"
      ]
    },
    {
      "ObjectType": "VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.Configuration.Processing.WorkItemMigrationConfig",
      "ReplayRevisions": true,
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
      "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
      "UpdateSourceReflectedId": false,
      "BuildFieldTable": false,
      "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
      "QueryBit": "AND  [System.AreaPath] = '****\\Market Regulation\\Market Surveillance – Bonds'  AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'Test Case' ",
      "OrderBit": "ORDER BY [System.Id]",
      "Enabled": true,
      "LinkMigration": true,
      "AttachmentMigration": true,
      "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
      "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
      "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": false,
      "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
      "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
      "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
      "AttachmentMazSize": 480000000,
      "CollapseRevisions": false
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your "OrderBit" syntax is wrong, it should look like this:

```
"OrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc"
```

Just adapt it to your situation.